# Push data instantly to frontend when adding data to database (Ushahidi)

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, kohana, ushahidi

I would like to realtime update my map view when someone adds a post without refreshing the page in Ushahidi(opensource website project). Its backend uses php (Kohana framework) and MySQL database, and front-end uses AngularJS. There might be not built-in mechanism about this. So I want to find out which materials are suitable.

First, I need to use event driven lib, such as [this](https://github.com/igorw/evenement), to detect database changes. Second, how to detect database changes. Third, use web socket based lib, such as [Socket.io](http://socket.io/), to realtime push data to the front-end to display.

I have read `echo` feature in Laravel php framework which seems to fit this, but not in Kohana. Is there any better approach in this system or some good references? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a simpler matter: **sending notifications**.
PHP is not suitable as a WebSocket server (though you can do this). It is better to write it in Node and notify it from PHP. WS server will continue to send notifications. You can also use a commercial service that will do it.

**Detection of changes in the database**: If the application has been correctly written (ie it uses `ORM`, not raw `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/REPLACE` queries) then it is enough to modify the `save` method using https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/ORM#changed data.

In case there are several raw queries you can handle them manually.

Otherwise, you can use triggers. Mark record as updated (eg: insert data to log/notification table). In the WebSocket server, you can periodically check this data and notify recipients.